# Delimiter string splitting

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, delimiter

I have a dataset which has some values delimited by '\n' and some values delimited by '\n\n'. I have written some code that works for each case separately but I was wondering if there is a method to include both of these delimiters so it splits them whether there is '\n' or '\n\n'. In the current setting it is throwing an error 'Columns must be same length as key'.

Code:

```
temp = result['personal_info'].str.replace(' -- ', '|').str.split('|', expand = True)
temp[[1,4]] = temp[1].str.split('\n', expand = True)
temp = temp.rename(columns={0: "occupation", 1: "country", 2: "employer_type", 3: "race", 4: "relationship_status"})
final_df = result
final_df = pd.concat([final_df, temp], axis=1, sort=False)
final_df = final_df.drop('personal_info', axis=1)
```

This code works for '\n', if I change it to '\n\n' it works for '\n\n'.

Sample input:

> 'Prof-specialty|United-States\n\nNever-married -- Local-gov|White'
>
> 'Prof-specialty|United-States\nNever-married -- Local-gov|White'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex with Pandas split:

```
temp[[1,4]] = temp[1].str.split('\n+', expand = True)
```

This splits if there’s at least one `\n`.